# How to add scrolling to the view when screen orientation is changed to landscape?

Tags: java, android, landscape

I have an Activity with several `TextEdits` and in portrait mode everything  is displayed perfectly.But when i switch the device to the landscape mode several views didn't displayed (they are cut).Can i in some way automatically add scrolling to the view when the device is switched to the landscape mode?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can try do this, this maybe helpful to you:

add ScrollView to your layout and set this flag `android:fillViewport="true"`
for example:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        // your layout

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Scroll will be enable when in your screen not enough space for items. Then you can scroll screen. 
So that if screen orientation is changed to landscape you can scroll items, and in portrait everything is displayed perfectly without ability to scroll.

Comment: android:fillViewport="true"  that is very important ,work for me tanx @Volodymyr

Answer (score 0):

Check when your device is in portrait mode and add :

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(yourContext);
scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
scroll.addView(yourView);
```

Comment: You should get a look at the doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

Comment: use getResources().getConfiguration().orientation to get the current orientation